# Is there a way to change the size of the contents of a GUI when the GUI is resized by the user?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window-resize

I've made a GUI using Tkinter. For the time being, I set the `geometry` to `'962x652'` and made it so the user can't resize it by using `.resizable(0, 0)`. I'm now looking for a way to make it so when the GUI is resized, all the elements change size as well along side it, preferably with the aspect ratio locked.

Is there a way to achieve this whilst making it so only the element change size visibly without changing actually changing size? For example, if my GUI contains a `scrolledtext` box, if the user was to resize the GUI, the `scrolledtext` will also increase in size, but so will the text and each line of text in it will stay in the same line. I hope that makes sense.

I've add some code down below to show what I'm working with. This should have a similar effect to what I currently have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

TrialGUI = Tk()
TrialGUI.title('Resize GUI')
TrialGUI.geometry('962x652+0+0')
#Remove the following so you can resize the GUI
TrialGUI.resizable(0, 0)

#These are the two frames. I've changed their colour so they are visible when they are resized.
ABC1b = Frame(TrialGUI, bg='lightpink', bd=20, width=900, height=600)
ABC1b.grid(row=0, column=0)
ABC2 = Frame(TrialGUI, bg='lightblue', bd=20, width=452, height=600)
ABC2.grid(row=0, column=1)

#This is the text box
txtQuestion = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(ABC1b, wrap=tk.WORD, width=42, height=10, font=(14))
txtQuestion.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=3)

#This inserts text into it. I made it insert which line the text should be in so it is easier to check if it is still in the same line when it is resized.
txtQuestion.insert(tk.INSERT, 'This should be in the first line.----------------------------------- This should be in the second line.------------------------------ This should be in the third line.----------------------------------')

TrialGUI.mainloop()
```

If anyone decides to play around with this code, remember to remove `TrialGUI.resizable(0, 0)` so it can be resized.

Comment: .pack() is probably the easiest way. You dont have good control but it resizes easily.

Comment: @ScottPaterson , I've already used .grid for everything I've done. I prefer to use it because it gives me better control over placements. But still thanks.